# How to Use the ConnectionString on Funq.Container?

Tags: servicestack, funq

How can you leverage the connection string property when initializing a registered type with the Funq.Container?  ServiceStack shows how to include a connection string while registering a type with the IoC container (Funq.Container) but I cannot find any examples actually using that connection string.  I'd like to use this on the client end to specify the base URI for my internal JsonClient.

The examples show this:

```
container.Register(new MyType(c.Resolve<IDependency>(), connectionString));
```

But none of the examples show anything ever happening with the `connectionString` variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What that example is saying is the container will create an instance of `MyType` for each request. When it creates an instance of `MyType`, the dependency `IDependency` will be passed as a parameter to the constructor of `MyType` and so will the `connectionString`.

Your example code needs an input parameter `c` though:

```cs
container.Register(c => new MyType(c.Resolve<IDependency>(), connectionString));
```

The usage of the `connectionString` is up to you. You can use it how you want in your object of `MyType`. You may wish to expose it as a public property, so it can be accessed. Or use it to alongside you `IDependency`. By way of an expanded example:

```cs
public class MyType
{
    private IDependency _someDependency;
    public string ConnectionString { get; private set }

    public MyType(IDependency dependency, string connectionString)
    {
        _someDependency = dependency.SetConnectionString(connectionString); // Assumes this method exists.
        ConnectionString = connectionString;
    }
}
```

In your service when `MyType` is autowired you now have access to the object.

```cs
public class MyService : Service
{
    public MyType MyType { get; set; }

    public void Get(SomeRequest request)
    {
         string connectionString = MyType.ConnectionString;
    }
}
```

If you wish to resolve `MyType` somewhere else you can use

```cs
MyType myType = HostContext.Container.Resolve<MyType>();
string connectionString = myType.ConnectionString;
```

I hope this clears up that all that is happening is the `connectionString` is passed into the object constructor and you are free to use it as you require.

Answer (score 1):

Check the docs again.  The paragraph directly above the section you referred to shows a delegate method where the object being instantiated requires a connection string.  I believe the author is trying to suggest that you could supply the connection string (or any other needed parameters) to the object via the constructor...

```
container.Register(c => new MyType(c.Resolve<IDependency>(), connectionString));
container.Register<IMyType>(c => new MyType(c.Resolve<IDependency>(), connectionString));
container.Register(c => CreateAndInitialzeMyType(c.Resolve<IDependency1>(), c.Resolve<IDependency2>));
```

In this example, the method being shown is the class' constructor method... which may require optional parameters.

The doc in question: [The IoC container](https://github.com/ServiceStackV3/ServiceStackV3/wiki/The-IoC-container)